# "Tigon" ethernet firmware: error message though working

Tags: debian, ethernet, firmware

This time I did not install firmware-linux-nonfree. I opted to avoid it and found that everything is working fine (well, my wireless indicator light doesn't work, but the adaptor does, so it's cool). Anyway, the last call to `update-initramfs` produced this error:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/tigon/tg3_tso5.bin for module tg3
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/tigon/tg3_tso.bin for module tg3
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/tigon/tg3.bin for module tg3
```

It is apparently the firmware for my ethernet adaptor. That is working fine, same as last install. How do I suppress this warning or fix the problem. I don't want the nonfree fw package as it conflicts with my AMD gf fw.

Comment: As the firmware is not free, you need to add nonfree repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't an error, just a warning. The `tg3` module drives many Broadcom chipsets, and needs these firmware files only for BCM5705 TSO, BCM5703/BCM5704 TSO and BCM5701A0. If you include a currently loaded module in your initramfs, but not all possible firmware files it can theoretically request, `update-initramfs` gives you these warnings. These tell you that the generated initramfs file isn't quite as general as it could be. You can only hack around this, for example by creating dummy firmware files.

Comment: It would seem the case, I haven't found any "clean" (hack-free) solution so I'm marking this as correct.

Answer (score 1):

About searching for firmware and which packages they might be found in, they general sollution is to search which package contain the firmware file.  This can of course be used for genera search for any file that is created by any package.

So as we are searching for `/lib/firmware/tigon/tg3.bin` etc. a suitable search string for firmware files that contain `tigon/tg3` in its path.

So the sollution for Debian based distributions is:

```
apt-file search tigon/tg3
```

or

```
dpkg-query -S tigon/tg3
```

And yes, the firmware are in package `linux-firmware` in Ubuntu (which I tried this on), and not free.  As there are no source files which you can use to compile them, so they are in `nonfree` repository.
So the solution for that is either ignore if Ethernet works, or add `nonfree` repository and install from there.

Look that up in relevant man page, [The Debian Administrator's Handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/) or [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/)

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer:

```
apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree
```

I fixed this some time ago, with the earlier apt line...

Comment: The OP specifically said they did not want the nonfree firmware.

Comment: But the firmware are not free, so if he want it, he need to use nonfree firmware.

Comment: On Ubuntu, you get this in the package `linux-firmware`, as can be found with `apt-file search tigon/tg3` or `dpkg-query -S tigon/tg3`.

Comment: This solution also requires you to enable the "non-free" repos in /etc/apt/sources.list by appending "non-free" to the appropriate lines.